# Searching an entire table row for a five digit number?

Tags: php, parsing, url, search, row

To put it simply, I'm trying to search an entire row for a 5 digit number that is parsed in via the URL.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die("Could not connect to    database!");

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM codes");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    if($code == $row['code'])
    {
        echo "Code valid";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid code";
        break;
    }
}
```

This code partly works, but only outputs "Code valid!" when the first value from the database (12345) is parsed in.

I've seen the mysql LIKE clause mentioned a few times here, but I haven't been able to get it to work so far. I'm still pretty amateur, so apologies if I'm completely missing something.

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Comment: The best approach would be to alter your query to only return the rows that you are interested in based on a `WHERE` clause of some sorts.

Comment: Remove the `break;` from your code if you want to check more rows than one (at the moment you only check the first row and then break the while loop).

Comment: Hello @william, welcome to the site. I've edited your post to fit more. :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work with like you would use something close to below. The `%` is used as a wildcard to match anything on either side of the query.

```
SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code LIKE '%12345%'
```

Or from your code

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code LIKE '%" . $code . "'");
```

But direct input into your sql without sanitation is bad practice. Below is a better option, but using PDO would be the best.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($code) . "'");
```

To check if code is valid you would change your while statement to the following

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "Code Valid";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        /* Output of codes if wanted */
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid code";
}
```

Comment: The code almost works, but does not display the error message when an invalid code is parsed.

Comment: You have to query the number of records returned using `mysqli_num_rows` to check if anything was returned. If `0` then it would return fail. Will update answer

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WHERE` clause:

```
$code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'code', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code = {$code}";
```

Using your code, if you want all results to be shown then simply remove the `break;` statements from the code; they stop the loop.